# How to run a task in background for every 5 minutes in xamarin ios in visual studio

Tags: c#, ios, visual-studio, xamarin.forms, cross-platform

I am working on xamarin forms cross platform application which supports both android and iOS, in this i need run a background task for every 5 minutes for iOS version.

How to Achieve this, can any one help me on this please.

Best Regards,
Srinivas.

Comment: Polling is rarely the right approach. It isn't efficient in its use of battery or network resources. You can refresh data as soon as the app returns to the foreground so that the user has the latest data or you could use push notifications from your server when there is new data

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that in iOS. Apple doesn't allow it. The best you'll be able to do is to schedule local notifications every 5 minutes. If the user opens the notification then your app will get launch, but if they cancel it you won't.

Comment: Actually i need to refresh Application data for every 5 minutes even if the app is in inactive, How can i do that?

Comment: Short answer: You can't.